# Scala's HashSet doesn't seem to implement Set?

Tags: scala, hashset

I have a Scala class:

```
class Example {
    def fooBar() : String = {
        // do some stuff

        var whistles = new HashSet[String]()
        fizzBuzz(whistles)

        // do some more stuff
    }

    def fizzBuzz(whistles : Set[String]) : Unit = {
        // do some stuff down here
    }
}
```

This gives me compiler errors when I call the `fizzBuzz` method (from inside `fooBar`), stating:

> type mismatch; found : java.util.HashSet[String] required: Set[String]

**What am I missing here?!?** `HashSet` implements `Set`, the last time I checked...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Scala has neat implementation of collections.It has two flavor of  collection.

1. Mutable collection (Read and write)

   **scala.collection.mutable.***
2. Immutable collection (read-only)

   **scala.collection.immutable.***

you should not confuse between two variants.

**Mutable**

```
    val mutableHashset = scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String]()
    mutableHashset += "name"
    mutableHashset.foreach { println }
```

**Immutable**

```
  val immutableHashSet = scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[String]("Name", "Age", "Address")
    immutableHashSet.foreach { println }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with immutable vs mutable collections? His error message indicates that he's using `java.utl.HashSet`.

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing `java.util.HashSet[A]`, the java version of `HashSet`, with `scala.collection.immutable.Set[A]`. You want `scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[A]` instead:

```
val whistles = scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[String]()
fizzBuzz(whistles)
```